# Vue js text field value becomes empty when new row is appended

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an dynamic table where new row can be added as well as removed ,im populating text field values based on Onchange event of Select option ,For the first row i can populate the values but once i append a new row ,the old values of the past row gets removed.

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            //editmode:true,
            templatename: '',
            type: 'margin',
            games: {},
            fields: {},
            subs: {},
            rows: []
            // errors: {},
        }
    },

    components: {
        Datepicker,
        MinusIcon,
        PlusIcon,
        XCircleIcon
    },

    methods: {



        getexcercisesrepcount: function(event, dynamicrow) {
            var currentrow = dynamicrow;
            var excercise = event;
            const URL = baseurl + `api/getexcercisesrepcount/`
            axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: URL,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    data: excercise
                })
                .then(response => {
                    var rowsdata = response.data;
                    var i = 0;

                    for (i; i < rowsdata.length; i++) {
                        var exid = rowsdata[i].id;
                        if (dynamicrow != null) {
                            var crval = $("#set" + currentrow).val(exid); //This is where i set value for the table row

                        }
                    }
                });

        },

        addRow: function() {

            var elem = document.createElement('tr');
            this.rows.push({

                workoutname: "",
                workoutcategory: "",
                set: "",
                rep: "",
                resttime: "",
                tempo: ""

            })

        },

        removeElement: function(index) {
            this.rows.splice(index, 1);
        },
    },
}
```

This is my table where i have added text fields as well as select option

```
<table class="border-collapse" style="width: 100%;" id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <th class="p-2 border border-solid d-theme-border-grey-light" width="25%">Workout</th>
        <th class="p-2 border border-solid d-theme-border-grey-light text-center" width="25%">Excercise</th>
        <th class="p-2 border border-solid d-theme-border-grey-light">Set</th>
        <th class="p-2 border border-solid d-theme-border-grey-light">Rep</th>
        <th class="p-2 border border-solid d-theme-border-grey-light">Rest time</th>
        <th class="p-2 border border-solid d-theme-border-grey-light">Tempo</th>
    </tr>
    <tr :id="'tr'+index" v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="index">
        <td class="p-2 border border-solid d-theme-border-grey-light">
            <vs-select v-model="row.workoutname" v-validate="'required'" @change="getworkoutexcercises($event)" name="workoutname[]" :id="'wrkout'+index" class="w-full select-large" autocomplete>
                <vs-select-item :key="game.id" :value="game.id" :text="game.workoutname" v-for="game in games" class="w-full" />
            </vs-select>
        </td>
        <td class="p-2 border border-solid d-theme-border-grey-light">
            <vs-select v-model="row.workoutcategory" v-validate="'required'" @change="getexcercisesrepcount($event,index)" name="workoutcategory[]" :id="'wrkcat'+index" class="w-full select-large" autocomplete>
                <vs-select-item :key="game.id" :value="game.id" :text="game.subexname" v-for="game in subs" class="w-full" />
            </vs-select>
        </td>
        <td class="p-2 border border-solid d-theme-border-grey-light"><input type="text" class="form-control" v-validate="'required'" v-model="row.exsets" name="set[]" :id="'set'+index" value="" /></td>
        <td class="p-2 border border-solid d-theme-border-grey-light"><input type="text" class="form-control" v-validate="'required'" v-model="row.rep" name="rep[]" :id="'rep'+index" /></td>
        <td class="p-2 border border-solid d-theme-border-grey-light"><input type="text" class="form-control" v-validate="'required'" v-model="row.resttime" name="resttime[]" :id="'resttime'+index" /></td>
        <td class="p-2 border border-solid d-theme-border-grey-light"><input type="text" class="form-control" v-validate="'required'" v-model="row.tempo" name="tempo[]" :id="'tempo'+index" /></td>
        <a v-on:click="removeElement(index);" style="cursor: pointer">
            <x-circle-icon size="1.5x" class="custom-class" style="margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 15px;color:red;"></x-circle-icon>
        </a>
    </tr>
</table>
<button style="margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:15px;" class="button btn-primary" @click="addRow">Add row</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create HTML in vue components, rather you should use the virtual DOM and things like v-for to create the HTML you want instead of doing it with createElement.

And in the case that you do use the v-dom and you run into a similar issue, you want to use `key` to uniquely tag each node so Vue knows what belongs with what.

But main point is that you shouldn't be manipulating the DOM directly from Vue functions ever. It's performance taxing and you lose the benefit of reactivity, as you have noticed.

Look into v-for and vue's documentation on rendering lists for what you are trying to achieve: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: What do you mean by Html in vue components ? @xander

Comment: The `addRow` function where you are calling `document.createElement('tr');` in order to create new HTML elements should be avoided

Comment: Instead of `var crval = $("#set" + currentrow).val(exid);` for setting the value by modifying the HTML data, you should create an array of objects that represents each row with all the data, and in the row you can use `<td class="...">{{ row.value }}</td>` A lot of your code you modifying the HTML directly, but you should modify the variables defined in `data()` and use the data on those variables to set properties and values directly in the HTML template.

Comment: ok let me try ,could you tell me where should i use  {{ row.value }} in value tag ?

Comment: `<vs-select-item :key="game.id" :value="game.id"` in here maybe? I'm not quite sure how your application functions to be honest.

Comment: hey like you said i created an variable called fields and got respond this.fields = response.data , now i can get all data but when i append a row all values of current row get shown in older row

Comment: You'll have to modify the `:key` value so that the `key` on the row matches what you want it to show. The `key` is how vue tracks which components belong to which HTML elements.

Comment: how can i do that where should i use :key ?

Comment: Try setting key to a unique ID or index that you have from response.data